# ngx-mat-datetime-picker not displaying time after migrating from angular12 to angular15 version

Tags: angular-material, angular15

We have migrated our angular11 project to angular15 version, and we have upgraded angular material version to 15 version. In angular11 version date picker was working fine,but after upgrading it is not displaying time

```
<div>
    <mat-form-field class="date-picker" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>From</mat-label>
        <input id="from_date" matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="frompicker" 
           [(ngModel)]="fromDate"
            (ngModelChange)="onFromToChanged()">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="frompicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #frompicker>
        </ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
    </mat-form-field>
    
    <mat-form-field class="date-picker" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>To</mat-label>
        <input id="toDate" matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="topicker" 
            [(ngModel)]="toDate"
            (ngModelChange)="onFromToChanged()">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="topicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #topicker [enableMeridian]="enableMeridian"></ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

this is our code, and in angular11 version it was working like this

[image]

but after migration getting like this, time not displaying and there is no tick button.

[image]

can anyone help me to figure out the issue

Answer (score 0):

Since the error appears within the time picker part (which is not part of the Angular Material datepicker component), I suppose that the problem is not within Angular Material's datepicker, but with the component from an external library `ngx-mat-datetime-picker`.

[That library is deprecated](https://github.com/h2qutc/ngx-mat-datetime-picker) and, according to the docs, it was only supported until Angular Material v9.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `defaultTime` input is no longer used in [`NgxMatTimepickerComponent`](https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/blob/master/projects/datetime-picker/src/lib/timepicker.component.ts#L41)

`@Input() defaultTime: number[];` is declared but no longer used in the component.

It seems to be a regression from this [commit](https://github.com/h2qutc/angular-material-components/commit/1d7387ac2b9ab0fb345ef270d6cca5d25d07536a#diff-e86261738f9bb13f371b908134174121ecb4bec97eb1b1e7c2e9d8fca3af13bcL115) where this instruction `this._dateAdapter.setTimeByDefaultValues(this._model, this.defaultTime);` has been removed

You can add manually a button using the directive `ngxMatDatepickerApply`, you can see an example in the [documentation](https://h2qutc.github.io/angular-material-components/#/datetimepicker)

```
<ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker>
  <ngx-mat-datepicker-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" ngxMatDatepickerApply>Apply</button>
  </ngx-mat-datepicker-actions>
</ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the below style and display problem fixed for me!

```
    ngx-mat-timepicker {
        .mat-mdc-form-field-flex {
            padding: 0 !important;
        }
    }
```